# How to upload multiple csv files to R shiny and rename duplicate values using file names?

Tags: r, shiny

Here is the reproducible data:

```
file1 <- data.frame(animal = c('cat','dog','horse'), w = c(10,20,30))
file2 <- data.frame(animal = c('pig','dog','bat'), w = c(11,22,33))
file3 <- data.frame(animal = c('dog','eagle','horse'), w = c(110,220,330))
write.csv(file1, 'foobar_TEST_1.csv')
write.csv(file2, 'foobar_TEST_2.csv')
write.csv(file3, 'foobar_TEST_3.csv')
```

I would like to upload all 3 files and if the values under 'animal' column are duplicates, rename only the duplicates using the last part of file names. From our data:
dog, dog_TEST_2, dog_TEST_3, horse, horse_TEST_2

Here's the Shiny code and ideally, I'd like to implement the code in the reactive():

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
  fileInput(inputId = "animal",
            label = "Upload Multiple Files",
            multiple = T,
            accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                       ".csv"))),
  
  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table1")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$animal)
    inFile <- input$animal$datapath
    df <- lapply(inFile, function(y){
      files <- read.csv(y, header=TRUE)
    })
    final <- do.call(rbind, df)
    
    list(final = final)
  })
  
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    final <- data()$final
    datatable(data = final)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's more an issue in data wrangling than in `shiny`. (; As a first step add the filename to each df when reading your datasets. Second step would be to keep only the part of the filenames you want to use to label your duplicates. Finally, rename the duplicated animals.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$animal)
    inFile <- input$animal$datapath
    inFile_names <- input$animal$name
    
    df <- Map(function(x, y) {
      files <- read.csv(x, header = TRUE)
      files$file <- y
      files
    }, inFile, inFile_names)
    final <- do.call(rbind, df)
    row.names(final) <- NULL
    
    final$file <- gsub("^foobar_(.*?)\\.csv$", "\\1", final$file)
    dups <- duplicated(final$animal)
    final$animal[dups] <- paste(final$animal[dups], final$file[dups], sep = "_")
    final$file <- NULL
    
    list(final = final)
  })

  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    final <- data()$final
    DT::datatable(data = final)
  })
}
```

[image]